# Snackbar sometimes doesn't show up when it replaces another one

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I encountered a weird issue with Snackbars on android. I show error messages via an Snackbar + Retry-Action. When 'Retry' is clicked and the error is still here (e.g. no internet) I show the error again.
This click on the action in the Snackbar automatically dismisses the currently shown one, and showing a new Snackbar while the old one still 'fades out' works as expected.

But sometimes (when I click 'Retry' ~30 times) a Snackbar doesn't show up at all after I press the button many times.

I can reproduce it with this simple code:

```
final View.OnClickListener retryListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showSnackbar();
    }
};

private void showSnackbar() {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(root, "Error", BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Retry", retryListener)
            //Callback only for debugging-purposes
            .addCallback(new BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback<Snackbar>() {
                @Override
                public void onShown(Snackbar transientBottomBar) {
                    super.onShown(transientBottomBar);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onShown called");
                }
            });
    snackbar.show();
    Log.d(TAG, "show called");
}
```

When I take a look at logcat after the problem occurs with this code, the last line is `show called` and the `onShown`-callback wasn't called anymore.

Why would this happen? Should I report this as an issue? Any workarounds known?

Comment: Did you find solve this issue?

Comment: @Taranmeet I found a workaround, see my answer

Answer (score 8):

I haven't found a real reason why it happens nor a real solution to the problem, but I found a workaround which works for me:

```
private Snackbar currentlyShownSnackbar;    

private void showSnackbar() {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(...);
    snackbar.show();
    currentlyShownSnackbar = snackbar;
}
```

Simply by keeping a reference to the currently shown Snackbar, this problem doesn't happen anymore. I don't know why, maybe it is related to too early garbage-collection.

Code inspection will say that this variable is assigned but never used - this warning can be ignored.

I also added this in my Activity to prevent any possible memory leak:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.currentlyShownSnackbar = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Day, I had same problem and I´d fixed the problem with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you dismiss the current `SnackBar` and wait a little to show it again, it works. I'm using a [Kotlin Extension Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) to make it simpler to use:

```
fun Snackbar.dismissAndShow() {
    if (isShownOrQueued) {
        dismiss()
        view.postDelayed(1000L) { show() }
    } else {
        show()
    }
}
```

So then I call it like:

```
mySnackBar.dismissAndShow()
```